# Cannot make git diff use diff.external for external diff tool

Tags: git, ubuntu, diff

I am using git with the default Ubuntu 12.04 packages:

> git --version 
>   git version 1.7.9.5

I cannot find any mechanism that works to get git diff to open the external diff tool it seems to completely ignore any setting that I use.  I finally tried to force it to use my tool by using

> git -c diff.external=/home/john/bin/git-meld diff --ext-diff

but that did not work either (still invoking diff --cc)

I have also tried setting GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF as well as trying git diftool --tool=meld (which also strangely invokes diff -cc).  I am completely stumped as to why my diff tool settings are being ignored by git.  I find the diff -cc output inscrutable because I have been using GUI diff tools for so long.

Should I try updating to a newer git?

Thanks for any help!
John

My git config settings are below:

> git config -l
>
> user.name=jmicco user.email=parent.bank.app@gmail.com
>   diff.external=/home/john/bin/git-meld
>   diff.tool.external=/home/john/bin/git-meld core.editor=emacs
>   core.repositoryformatversion=0 core.filemode=true core.bare=false
>   core.logallrefupdates=true
>   remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   remote.origin.fetch=refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
>   remote.origin.url=ssh://jmicco@review.gerrithub.io:29418/jmicco/allowance-app
>   remote.origin.pushurl=ssh://jmicco@review.gerrithub.io:29418/jmicco/allowance-app
>   remote.origin.push=HEAD:refs/for/master branch.master.remote=origin
>   branch.master.merge=master
>   remote.gerrit.url=ssh://jmicco@review.gerrithub.io:29418/jmicco/allowance-app
>   remote.gerrit.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gerrit/*
>   remote.gerrit.fetch=refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
>   remote.gerrit.pushurl=ssh://jmicco@review.gerrithub.io:29418/jmicco/allowance-app
>   remote.gerrit.push=HEAD:refs/for/master gerrit.createchangeid=true

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF="/bin/echo" git diff
```

It should print something like:

```
foo.c /tmp/T1NuN5_foo.c 240b63429c3267f8141ee0f33be9d12fc46216d3 100755 foo.c 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100755
```

Then everything is ok with your git version.

`diff.external=/home/john/bin/git-meld` is an invalid setting. Git expects the external diff program to recognize the git-specific arguments and produce a standard diff output. Meld won't do that.

I think you need `git difftool -t meld`

Comment: "diff.external=/home/john/bin/git-meld is an invalid setting." Doesn't that depend on the contents of `git-meld`? A common strategy seems to be to make a file `git-meld` which runs `meld $2 $5`.